# xstream is converting &amp; to & when converting from xml to Java Objects

Tags: java, xml, xstream

xstream is converting `&amp;` to `&` when converting from xml to Java Objects. 
I don't want this to happen. How shall I do it?

```
 XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());

            xstream.processAnnotations(HelpConfigVO.class);
            xstream.processAnnotations(ProductVO.class);
            xstream.processAnnotations(PackageVO.class);
            xstream.addImplicitCollection(HelpConfigVO.class, "packages");
            configVO = (HelpConfigVO)xstream.fromXML(helpConfigData);
```

Secondly, The output XML I am getting from xstream is not formatted. How do I format my xml to make it readable?

Comment: *"I don't want this to happen."* - Why? It's the right thing.

Comment: Thanks Guys. I understand now that it is the correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> xstream is converting `"&amp;"` to `"&"` when converting from xml to Java Objects.

As it should.  It would be broken if it didn't

> I don't want this to happen.

Why?  The `"&amp;"` in the XML *means* `"&"`.

> How shall I do it?

No valid XML parser will do this for you because it is an egregious violation of the XML spec.  In theory, you could hack an open source XML parser to do this abominable act ... but I'd strongly advise against it.

---

If correct behavior in the parser is causing you problems, you've got a flaw in your application design.  You should do something like:

- not parsing the XML - store it as character sequence, OR
- reinsert the character entities by applying the XML escape mapping to the text before you use it.

Answer (score 3):

The website for the software says "XStream is a simple library to serialize objects to XML and back again". Since `&amp;` is XML for `&` it wouldn't make sense for it not to convert it, and I doubt very much it has a "Convert to text except for ampersands which would continue to be XML" feature.

It sounds like you have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want `&amp;` in the data?

Assuming that it is because you are outputting XML or HTML, the appropriate solution is to treat the text as text and either:

- Use the "insert text" feature of whatever library you are using to build the XML/HTML (as opposed to the "insert markup" feature)
- Run the text though an escaping function (such as Perl's [HTML::Entities](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Entities) module or PHP's [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) function (I don't use Java enough to recommend one for that language, but the principle is the same)).

Comment: +1 for the "XY problem". Finally I know the name for this pattern, my life makes sense again.

Answer (score 1):

`&amp;`is a XML entity.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML

It makes sense that XStream unescapes it to `&` for a Java String.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `&amp;` means ampersant; it's correct for xstream to do this.  If you really want the output to be `"&amp;"`, you need `&&amp;amp;` in your code, or put it inside a [CDATA section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA).